# The graphs of $f(x)=ax^2 +2bx + c$ and $g(x)=5x^2-3bx-a$ meet at some point for all real values of $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, quadratics

Let $a_m(m=1,2,3,...,p)$ be the possible integral value of $a$ for which the graphs of $f(x)=ax^2 +2bx +  c$ and $g(x)=5x^2-3bx-a$ meet at some point  for all real values of $b$. Let $t_r=\prod_{m=1}^p(r-a_m)$ and $S_n=\sum_{r=1}^nt_r$ , $n$ belonging to set of all natural numbers.

Then find the minimum possible value of $a$ and the sum of values of $n$ for which $S_n$ vanishes. Also, find the value of $\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{t_r}$.

I first thought of solving the two parabolic curves but it would become tedious.

*This question is from one of the textbooks for the IITJEE exam.
The question had no subsequent details.*

*P.S. - I have again posted this question despite getting negative feedback. Please enlighten me*

Comment: Is there nobody to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider $f(x)-g(x)=0,$ i.e.
$$(a-5)x^2+5bx+a+c=0\tag1$$

We want $(1)$ to have at least one real solution for all $b$.

- For $c=-5$ and $a=5$, $(1)$ has a solution $x=0$ for all $b$.
- For $c=-5$ and $a\not=5$, $(1)$ does not have any real solutions for $b=0$.
- For $c\not=-5$ and $a=5$, $(1)$ does not have any real solutions for $b=0$.
- For $c\not=-5$ and $a\not=5$, considering the discriminant of $(1)$, we see that $(5b)^2-4(a-5)(a+c)\ge 0$ holds for all $b$ if and only if $(a-5)(a+c)\le 0$, i.e.
  $$\min(5,-c)\le a\le \max(5,-c)\tag2$$

---

**Case 1** : $c\le -6$

It follows from $a\not=5$ and $(2)$ that $a=6,7,\cdots, k$ where $k=\lfloor -c\rfloor$.

$$\begin{align}S_n&=\sum_{r=1}^n(r-6)(r-7)\cdots (r-k)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{k-4}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\bigg((r-5)(r-6)\cdots (r-k)-(r-6)(r-7)\cdots (r-k-1)\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{(n-5)(n-6)\cdots (n-k)-(-5)(-6)\cdots (-k)}{k-4}\end{align}$$
using the idea of [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

If $k$ is odd, then there is no positive integer $n$ such that $S_n=0$.

If $k$ is even, then $S_n=0\iff n-5=k\iff n=k+5$.

Also, $\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{t_r}$ is undefined since $t_6=0$.

(This answer considers $\sum_{\color{red}r=5}^{\infty}(1/t_r)$ instead of  $\sum_{t=5}^{\infty}(1/t_r)$ you wrote.)

---

**Case 2** : $-6\lt c\lt -4$

From $(2)$, the only possible $a$ is $a=5$. 
$$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n}(r-5)=\frac{n(n-9)}{2}$$
So, $S_n=0\iff n=9$, and $\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{t_r}$ is undefined since $t_5=0$.

---

**Case 3** : $-4\le c$

It follows from $a\not=5$ and $(2)$ that $a=k, k+1,\cdots, 4$ where $k=\lceil -c\rceil$.

$$\begin{align}S_n&=\sum_{r=1}^n(r-k)(r-k-1)\cdots (r-4)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{6-k}\sum_{r=1}^n\bigg((r+1-k)(r-k)\cdots (r-4)-(r-k)(r-k-1)\cdots (r-5)\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{(n+1-k)(n-k)\cdots (n-4)-(1-k)(-k)\cdots (-4)}{6-k}\end{align}$$

**Case 3-1** : $k=4$, i.e. $-4\le c\lt -3$

$$S_n=\frac{(n-3)(n-4)-(-3)(-4)}{2}$$
So, $S_n=0\iff n=7$.
$$\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{t_r}=\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{r-4}=+\infty$$

**Case 3-2** : $k=3$, i.e. $-3\le c\lt -2$

$$S_n=\frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)-(-2)(-3)(-4)}{3}$$
There is no positive integer $n$ such that $S_n=0$.
$$\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{t_r}=\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{(r-3)(r-4)}=\sum_{r=5}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1}{r-4}-\frac{1}{r-3}\bigg)=1$$

**Case 3-3** : $k=2$, i.e. $-2\le c\lt -1$
$$S_n=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)-(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)}{4}$$
So, $S_n=0\iff n=5$.
$$\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{t_r}=\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{(r-2)(r-3)(r-4)}=\sum_{r=5}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1/2}{(r-3)(r-4)}-\frac{1/2}{(r-2)(r-3)}\bigg)=\frac 14$$

**Case 3-4** : $k\le 1$, i.e. $c\ge -1$

$$S_n=\frac{(n+1-k)(n-k)\cdots (n-4)}{6-k}$$
So, $S_n=0\iff n=1,2,3,4$.
$$\small\begin{align}\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{t_r}&=\sum_{r=5}^\infty\frac{1}{(r-k)(r-k-1)\cdots (r-4)}
\\\\&=\frac{1}{k-4}\sum_{r=5}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{(r-k)(r-k-1)\cdots (r-3)}-\frac{1}{(r-k-1)(r-k-2)\cdots (r-4)}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{(4-k)(4-k)!}\end{align}$$

---

**Conclusion** :

The minimum possible value of $a$ is
$$\begin{cases}6&\text{if $\ \ c\le -6$}
\\\\5&\text{if $\ -6\lt c\lt -5$}
\\\\\lceil -c\rceil&\text{if $\ -5\le c$}\end{cases}$$

The sum of values of $n$ for which $S_n$ vanishes is

$$\begin{cases}\text{none}&\text{if $\ \ c\le -6$ and $\lfloor -c\rfloor$ is odd}
\\\\\lfloor -c\rfloor+5&\text{if $\ \ c\le -6$ and $\lfloor -c\rfloor$ is even}
\\\\9&\text{if $\ -6\lt c\lt -4$}
\\\\7&\text{if $\ -4\le c\lt -3$}
\\\\\text{none}&\text{if $\ -3\le c\lt -2$}
\\\\5&\text{if $\ -2\le c\lt -1$}
\\\\10&\text{if $\ -1\le c$}
\end{cases}$$

and $$\sum_{t=5}^\infty\frac{1}{t_r}=\begin{cases}\text{undefined}&\text{if $\ \ c\lt -4$}
\\\\+\infty&\text{if $\ -4\le c\lt -3$}
\\\\\bigg(4-\lceil -c\rceil)(4-\lceil -c\rceil)!\bigg)^{-1}&\text{if $\ -3\le c$}
\end{cases}$$